# CreateJS EaselJS draw bitmap video in iOS

Tags: ios, html, html5-video, easeljs, createjs

some code:

```
            video = document.createElement('video');
            video.setAttribute('webkit-playsinline');
            video.src = 'movie.mp4';
            var Video = new createjs.Bitmap(video);

            stage.addChild(Video);
```

I'm working on a rich media web app for iPad with CreateJS.
On desktop browsers drawing a bitmap video to the canvas/stage works fine, but on iOS it does "nothing".
I want to have an animated object above the video, so this is why, I think, the video needs to be drawn inside the canvas.

Does anyone have experience with that?

How can I achieve integrating a video with EaselJS and get it working on iPad/iPhone … ?

Comment: Would layering the canvas tag over the video tag via css be an option here? Also, have you tried wiring up Mobile Safari's debugger to see if there are any errors thrown on iOS?

Comment: I get 2 errors from mobile safari, but I don't understand them: 1.) Unable to get image data from canvas because the canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data. 2.) An error has occurred. This is most likely due to security restrictions on reading canvas pixel data with local or cross-domain images.

Comment: Are you loading the video from another domain?

Comment: no! it's the same code like above .. i know, that's pretty strange

Comment: Yeah, strange. I'm not getting any error but I'm having the same results. Works in desktop. Not on iOS.

Comment: how uncool is that? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function drawImage() isn't available to iOS and therefore, the method of drawing the video to the canvas directly isn't possible on iOS. See the explanation from [this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/HTML-canvas-guide/PuttingVideoonCanvas/PuttingVideoonCanvas.html) below.

Note: Video as a source for the canvas drawImage() method is not currently supported on iOS.